# Delete Repo Where Someone Else Comitted Changes

Tags: git, github, repository, github-pages

I am working with my github account A where I have deployed a website via github pages. Accidentally, I committed all changes using account B. How can I delete this repo from account A now? I don't see any option of "Settings"

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a new browser session (in private mode) and log in as B on github.com

In that separate session, you will be able to delete B's repository, through its settings.

Comment: I just realized that I was logged into the wrong account all this time!